# Slicing movie audio according to timings present in its .srt

Tags: audio, movie

I have extracted audio track from a movie. I've its subtitle file in .srt format. I want to slice the audio in to speech files according to timings that are available in subtitle file so that I can get transcribed speech data. Please suggest any method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do the same. There is tool named [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) where I can slice an audio by giving start point and duration as input. I stored start time and duration of speech of a movie in an excel file. By using a small python script I was able to automate the process.

Comment: I am working on the same problem. Could you kindly give me some guidance regarding this, or share your code resources for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.